# Windows 8.1 wireless doesn't work

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I purchased a Cybertron desktop recently. It came pre-installed with Windows 8.1

Here are its specs ([link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D1KWS3I)):

**System**: AMD FX 6300 3.50GHz 6-Core; AMD 760G Chipset; 16GB DDR3; 1TB HDD; Genuine Windows 8.1 64-bit

**Gaphics**: NVIDIA GeForce GT 640 2GB Video Card (Replaced it with NVIDIA 750 Ti; 24X DVD±RW Dual-Layer Drive; Audio: 7.1 Channel; Gigabit LAN

**Wireless**: 802.11b/g/n Wireless (The NVIDIA 750Ti was too big to have the internal wireless
card, so I got a Linksys AC1200 USB Network Adaptor

If I use an Ethernet cable, I can connect to the internet completely fine.
But if I try to use Wi-Fi, the connection is completely horrid.

My computer can connect to my router just fine, and the only problem that Windows ever found while troubleshooting was the following image:

[image]

When I try to connect to websites, the browser continuously tries to load the page without success like 75% of the time. Sometimes, my connection seems to work perfectly, but this only lasts a short amount of time.

I have tried all of these:

- Updating network adapter driver
- Uninstalling and re-installing the network adapter driver
- *ipconfig/dnsflush* in command prompt
- So, so many other things that I read online, none of which helped

Also, I have an Acer laptop as well that is running Windows 8.1 64-bit, and its wireless works fantastic.

If you have any ideas at all, please, please, please let me know!

Comment: 2.4Ghz or 5.0Ghz?

Comment: It says it uses either. I will add that to the question

Comment: But which one is your network using.  If you have a two separate networks ( one and each frequency ) does this problem exist on both? DNS problems are easy enough to fix.

Comment: http://imgur.com/WUCkeEO <-- Does that mean it is 5 Ghz?

Comment: 802.11n can broadcast at 2.4Ghz and 5.0Ghz.  This isn't a difficult question to answer.  What frequency is your router broadcasting at.

Comment: Sorry, it's 2.4 Ghz

Comment: A `802.11ac` adapter entire benefit is 5.0ghz support.  Your problems are likely connected to the 2.4 frequency being used.

Comment: So... How do I fix it?

Comment: Try uninstalling the  802.11ac adapter driver and try a multiband adapter driver. For my solution, I went through quite a few drivers before I found the one the worked.