# Why can't I reconnect to WiFi without reenabling "plane mode" in WIndows 8.1?

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

If I connected to any network, I should enable and disable "plane mode" to connect to other network or reconnect to the same. If I try to connect without this, I see monitor with red cross in tray for a second and then message about failure (in tray icon with connections available).
It happens on laptop and tablet both on Windows 8.1 in any network. All drivers are up to date and the latest Windows updates installed.
It is fine in Windows 7 on the same laptop.

Comment: You are dual booting Operating Systems on this laptop and one OS isn't handling networks properly? Which OS was installed first? Was it a clean install from install media or was it purchased with the OS on it? I suppose what I am trying to ask is whether there are any OEM provided applications on the system that may be getting in the way... Such as ConfigFree which is commonly bundled with Toshiba Laptops.

Comment: @NathanialMeek Laptop has clean 8.1 install, no dualboot. It was with 7 initialy. tablet is 8.1 and always was, no dualboot possible.

Comment: When you say that all the drivers are up to date, did you get them directly from the manufacturers website or let them update through Windows Update?

Comment: @NathanialMeek Initialy I install manufacturers drivers and then update from WU, but it changes nothing. Looks like some Windows update creates the trouble, but don't know which specific.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/665402/windows-8-1-update-effectively-disabled-wireless-networking?rq=1)
I want explicitly point out: choose 'multiband' driver, no other driver works